# Single page application with file treeview using ajax/php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

I am currently working with a web-based document management system, I am creating it as a single page using ajax/php connection. I have my file tree view, that displays the folders and files using this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['displayFolderAndFiles'])) {

    function listIt ($path) {
        $items = scandir($path);
        foreach ($items as $item) {

            // Ignore the . and .. folders
            if ($item != "." AND $item != "..") {
                if (is_file($path . $item)) {
                    // this is the file
                }
                else {
                    // this is the directory

                    // do the list it again!

                    echo "<li><span class='fa fa-chevron-right caret'></span><button class='btn-der' id='directory" . $id . "' onclick='directoryAction(this);' value='" . $path . $item . "/'>" . $item . "</button>";
                    echo "<ul class='nested'>";
                    listIt($path . $item . "/");
                    //echo("<input type='text' value='".$path.$item."/'>");
                    echo "</ul></li>";

                }
                $id++;
            }
        }
    }

    listIt("./My Files/");
}
```

with this code it is hard for me to manipulate the tree view. I use ajax to get the result.

What I want is to reload the tree view when i add, delete file or folder. I also want to load the page once I do some queries in my application without refreshing the page.

I want to have the functionalities like the sample image, the application is FileRun.

Can someone recommend or suggest some ways to address my problem.
Will I use some javascript library or else?

[Reference/Sample: Web-based Document Management System (FileRun)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP522.png)

Comment: why are you making html right  into it, make arrays and append into html on client side

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public function treeArr($dir){
        //  First we get the directory
        $paths = scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE);
        //  We remove .. && . from our array
        unset($paths[array_search('.', $paths, true)]);
        unset($paths[array_search('..', $paths, true)]);
        //  Add empty array for our tree
        $arr = [];
        //  Check isour paths array empty
        if (count($paths) < 1)
            return;
        //  If not empty we get through all paths and add what we want
        foreach($paths as $path){
            $current_dir = $dir.'/'.$path;
            $isDir = is_dir($current_dir);
            $expandable = count( scandir( $current_dir ) ) > 2 ? true : false;
            //  In my case, I needed path name
            //  Is it expandable (as is it directory and does it contains or is it empty)
            //  Is it dir or file, if it is not dir it will be false so its file
            //  And path for that folder or file

            $path_data = [
                'name' => $path,
                'expandable' => $expandable,
                'isDir' => $isDir,
                'path' => $current_dir,
            ];

            if($expandable) $path_data['data'] = $this->treeArr($dir.'/'.$path);
            //  If our dir is expandable we go to read files and folders from in it and call self function with that path

            array_push($arr, $path_data);
            //  At the end we add everything into array
        }
        return $arr;
    }
```

It works for my needs and on client side you can style and add this as you like.
Within foreach you can check for other things, like file extension, date, size and pass everything you need about that. Like if it is html file and you have some live editor, you can check is it html and if it is add like `'isHTML' => true,` and then on front:

```
if(file.isHTML) { //run the code }
```

Comment: where can I add/pass my specific directory?